# What does red text on a green line mean in a AWS Pull Request diff?

Tags: diff, aws-codecommit

Today I saw this for the first time in a pull request diff in AWS. The line is green and with a plus, so it is added. But the text is red and with slightly red background. The file is a SpecFlow (*.feature) file.

Does it signify spell-checker, or something else?

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's related to syntax highlighting. (1) Have you browsed to other SpecFlow files that have `And` lines? What is their highlighting like? (2) Have you looked at the DOM to see if there are classes applied here with interesting names? (3) I have found no indication that CodeCommit or Cloud9 supports syntax highlighting for this file type, so it might be automatically using rules that are designed for a different language/format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used SpecFlow or AWS CodeCommit, but a little bit of experimentation (for lack of thorough available documentation) strongly suggests that AndrewF's suspicion is correct:

[image: aws-codecommit diff between two SpecFlow feature files]

Syntax highlighting rules highlight invalid statements for a SpecFlow feature file (example found on [toolsqa.com](https://www.toolsqa.com/specflow/feature-file/)) are highlighted with red background. On the left, the same rule seems to cause the grey background for removed invalid statements.

The highlighting rules seem to support *`And`* clauses, just not in the `Then` part of a scenario, although the language grammar *seems* to allow this. I blame a bad syntax highlighting rule.

<sub>However, I have a hard time finding a formal grammar specification for Cuccumber/Gherkin that would tell me *exactly* what is and isn't allowed where (and what a compliant parser would make of it).</sub>

#### Edit

Why didn't I think of checking the source view first? Looking at the HTML/CSS rules of the above diff, one can see the markup in black and white: Red background equals `<span class="err">`. The same applies to the grey `Foo` on the left side of the diff.

[image: Source view of the diff]